# Exception encountered during startup - Emptied cassandra.yaml file

Tags: cassandra-2.1

Am using Cassandra 2.1.13
As part of some execution when C* was actually starting up and while C* start process was not complete, in mid of this operation the machine got rebooted.
Strangely the C* configuration file cassandra.yaml is emptied when checked later and following exception seen.

Is it because of emptied conf file cassandra.yaml with no contents or the following exception did result in emptying the cassandra.yaml file?

```
ERROR [main] DatabaseDescriptor.java:147 - Fatal error during configuration loading
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(TreeMap.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.util.TreeMap.<init>(TreeMap.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.logConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:126) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:104) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:84) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:161) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:168) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:564) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:653) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
ERROR [main] CassandraDaemon.java:581 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:168) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:564) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:653) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1347) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:58) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:149) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Could anyone please help me to find the root cause for this issue? Please do let me know If you need more details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified cassandra.yaml filr from standard config file without any changes? it seems some syntax error.

Comment: The cassandra.yaml file at the standard location itself is empty. Am suspecting was it because of reboot while the start up of Cassandra was in progress?

Comment: Not sure, So just put the yaml file with configuration it will work.

Comment: Yeah sure it will work, any pointers for the root cause for this file going empty. Wan't able to find anything related on blogs though.

Comment: Sure,I will put here if I get any leads.